# How to change keyboard config automagically when plugging USB keyboard to laptop (and get a deterministic behaviour)?

Tags: linux-mint, usb, keyboard, udev

I'm using Linux Mint 20. udev rules are just getting on my nerves. Sometimes they work, other times they don't.

Again, today they don't work.

I always end up copying stuff on the web, then tweak it, then end up with a working config, just to discover a few weeks/months later they stop working.

Once and for all, I'd really like to get a deterministic solution.

- What I want: that the external USB keyboard config changes (swap caps&ctrl + lwin compose) automatically when I plug the keyboard to my laptop.
- What I did:

a) Got my USB keyboard device info:

```
# lsusb |grep Dell
Bus 001 Device 045: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp.
```

b) In my /etc/udev/rules.d/90-keyboard_swapcaps.rules, I added:

```
## DEBUG
ACTION=="change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2107", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo == >> /tmp/udev-env.txt; env >> /tmp/udev-env.txt'"
# ACTUAL
ACTION=="change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2107", ENV{XKBLAYOUT}="fr", ENV{XKBOPTIONS}+="ctrl:swapcaps", ENV{XKBOPTIONS}+="compose:lwin"
```

c) Then I ran:

```
# udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

- What I get:

a) Nothing changes in the  keyboard configuration.

b) Monitoring

```
# udevadm monitor -u
...
UDEV  [10555.979594] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001E/input/input55 (input)
UDEV  [10555.989903] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001E/input/input55/input55::numlock (leds)
UDEV  [10555.992442] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/0003:046D:C077.001D/input/input54 (input)
UDEV  [10555.994812] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001E/input/input55/input55::scrolllock (leds)
UDEV  [10556.001225] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001E/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [10556.003513] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/0003:046D:C077.001D/input/input54/mouse1 (input)
UDEV  [10556.005834] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/0003:046D:C077.001D/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
UDEV  [10556.010005] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001E/input/input55/input55::capslock (leds)
UDEV  [10556.019614] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001E/input/input55/input55::numlock (leds)
UDEV  [10556.021307] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001E/input/input55/input55::scrolllock (leds)
UDEV  [10556.022045] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001E/input/input55/event20 (input)
UDEV  [10556.024438] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001E/input/input55/input55::capslock (leds)
UDEV  [10556.026259] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001E (hid)
```

Which tells me the device is detected & is the correct one

c) In /tmp/udev-env.txt, many lines similar to:

```
...
==
ID_FOR_SEAT=leds-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_1_2_1_0
ACTION=change
TRIGGER=kbd-scrolllock
SEQNUM=17431
USEC_INITIALIZED=10059229961
TAGS=:seat:
XKBLAYOUT=fr
XKBOPTIONS=ctrl:swapcaps compose:lwin
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.001C/input/input53/input53::scrolllock
SUBSYSTEM=leds
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_1_2_1_0
PWD=/
```

Which tells me the rules match and are applied.

What in the end am I doing wrong for my keyboard config not to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables only propagate from parent process to the child, never from child to parent. And anything run from udev rules will normally have no access to the environment of your GUI session anyway.

In your case, the shell process that was started by the `RUN+=` part of the udev rule certainly had the `XKBLAYOUT` and `XKBOPTIONS` environment variables set the way you wanted. But as soon as the commands in the `RUN+=...` are completed, that shell exits... and those modified environment variables will die along with it, without having any effect on anything.

Those environment variables would take effect only if the information in them is passed to the `setxkbmap` command or similar... which in your distribution may happen as a standard part of X11 session setup. Just setting the variables themselves without passing their values to the X11 server in some way does nothing at all to the keyboard layout.

Since the X11 session setup usually sources `/etc/profile` and similar shell startup files to provide a reasonable environment for GUI applications, it might be that just setting those variables in `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` or similar might **appear** to work. But the actual magic is not in the variables, but in the X11 session setup process which will execute `setxkbmap -layout $XKBLAYOUT ...` or equivalent based on the value of those variables. And that's the part you have not provided in your udev rules at all.

The execution context of the udev rules has nothing at all to do with the execution context of your GUI session. So even if you added a `setxkbmap` command that used those variables to communicate the change to the X11 server, the shell started by the udev rule would not have neither `DISPLAY` nor `XAUTHORITY` variables referring to your GUI session and so the command would just emit a `Cannot open display` error message.

(The `DISPLAY` variable and the X session cookie file, either at `~/.Xauthority` or in a custom location pointed to by the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable are the two essential things needed to become part of the X11 GUI session or send commands to that session in any way.)

Frustratingly, there **almost** is a functionality that would neatly solve this problem. You could create a file named `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb` with this content:

```
evdev:input:b????v413Cp2107e*
  XKB_FIXED_LAYOUT="fr"
  # XKB_FIXED_OPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps compose:lwin" # Unfortunately this part has not been implemented yet!
```

As far as I understand, this would allow specifying a X11 keyboard layout *for that particular keyboard only*, even if the system has other keyboards with other layouts plugged in. Unfortunately the part that would allow specifying the *options* part of the XKB keyboard layout specification (which I guess would be the important part for you) is not implemented.